# Object reference crash in ViewWillAppear in PageRenderer xamarin forms ios

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, navigation, crash, toolbar

We customize the toolbar menu for navigation back button in xamarin forms ios. I am getting below crash in appcenter.
ToolbarMenuCustomRenderer.ViewWillAppear (System.Boolean animated)
SIGABRT: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Code snippet below:

```
public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

            CustomToolbarContentPage page = Element as CustomToolbarContentPage;
            if (page == null)
                return;

            #region for soft back button

            UIViewController root = NavigationController.TopViewController;
            if (!page.NeedOverrideSoftBackButton)
                return;

            string title = "<" + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(NavigationPage.GetBackButtonTitle(Element)) ? "" : NavigationPage.GetBackButtonTitle(Element));

            root.NavigationItem.SetLeftBarButtonItem(
                new UIBarButtonItem(title, UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, (sender, args) =>
                {
                    page.OnSoftBackButtonPressed();
                }), true);

            #endregion
        }
```

How to resolve this in xamarin forms ios?

Comment: you should get a stack trace that tells you which lines causes the error.  Can you replicate it, or is the only report you have from AppCenter?

Comment: ToolbarMenuCustomRenderer.ViewWillAppear (System.Boolean animated)
(wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr)
UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate)
UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName)
Application.Main (System.String[] args)

This only i am getting from appcenter.

Answer (score 0):

I create a sample app with your code and works fine, you can check the code below to see if you miss something:

**NewPage:**

```
    namespace My_Forms_test.Views
    {
        public partial class NewPage2 : ContentPage
        {
            public NewPage2()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
            public void OnSoftBackButtonPressed()
            {
                Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
            }
        }
    }
```

**CustomRenderer:**

```
  [assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(NewPage2),typeof(MyPageRenderer))]
    namespace My_Forms_test.iOS
    {
        public class MyPageRenderer:PageRenderer
        {
            public MyPageRenderer()
            {
            }
            public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
            {
                base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
                NewPage2 page=Element as NewPage2;
                UIViewController root = NavigationController.TopViewController;
                string title = "<" + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(NavigationPage.GetBackButtonTitle(Element)) ? " " : NavigationPage.GetBackButtonTitle(Element));
                root.NavigationItem.SetLeftBarButtonItem(
                    new UIBarButtonItem(title, UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, (sender, args) =>
                      { 
                          page.OnSoftBackButtonPressed();
                          Console.WriteLine("This method is trigged"); }), true);
            }
        }
```

Here are ScreenShots:

[image]

[image]

You can also refer to this documents https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/contentpage